# SHA256 message schedule examples

Tags: hash, sha-256

I need some example values for the message schedule stage of SHA256 to test this part of my implementation.

If possible in binary, for the string `'abc'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here it is, in hexadecimals representing big endian, 32-bit words:

```
-00--16-

61626380
00000000
00000000
00000000

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000

00000000
00000000
00000000
00000018

-16--32-

61626380
000F0000
7DA86405
600003C6

3E9D7B78
0183FC00
12DCBFDB
E2E2C38E

C8215C1A
B73679A2
E5BC3909
32663C5B

9D209D67
EC8726CB
702138A4
D3B7973B

-32--48-

93F5997F
3B68BA73
AFF4FFC1
F10A5C62

0A8B3996
72AF830A
9409E33E
24641522

9F47BF94
F0A64F5A
3E246A79
27333BA3

0C4763F2
840ABF27
7A290D5D
065C43DA

-48--64-

FB3E89CB
CC7617DB
B9E66C34
A9993667

84BADEDD
C21462BC
1487472C
B20F7A99

EF57B9CD
EBE6B238
9FE3095E
78BC8D4B

A43FCF15
668B2FF8
EEABA2CC
12B1EDEB
```